# Regex for at least two unique characters

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression to validate a password.

You can assume that the input contains only lower case letters, a-z.
The restriction is that there must be at least two letters which are unique.

Note that I do mean **unique** charactors; not just two **different** charactors. (If that makes sense?)

For example these are ok:

```
abc
abbc
aabc
```

These should fail:

```
aabb    //There are no unique letters.  The 'a' appears twice.
aabbcc  //There are no unique letters
abab    //There are no unique letters
abb     //There is only one unique letter
```

I know that just looping through the letters would be a much easier solution, but unfortunately I need this as a regex.

I have been trying various combinations of lookaheads etc. but no luck so far.

**EDIT:**

I have made a little progress.  I can now check for a single unique letter, using both a negative look behind and also a negative lookahead.  Like this:

```
(.)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1)
```

I expected I could just put this twice but it's not working.  Something similar to:

```
(.)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1)(.)(?<!\2.+)(?!.*\2)
```

Comment: The language you are specifying is not regular. (I don't think)  So it cannot be parsed by a regular expression.

Comment: @jjnguy, I'm not disputing that this _is_ a task for regex, but .NET's regex engine had recursive pattern matching, groups+ back-references, and arbitrary length look behind. In short: it is capable to match much more than regular languages! :)

Comment: @Bart, yup.  I know they are much more powerful than a 'traditional' regex.  I was just pointing out that you will have to get fancy if you want to make C# regex work in this case.

Comment: I don't get the distinction between 'abc' and 'aabbcc' as they both consist of more than two distinct characters.

Comment: @Will -- I didn't mention distinct charactors.  By unique charactors I mean charactors which only appear once.  In aabbcc the a appears twice.

Comment: Even if you solve this, I'm sorry for the guy that has to maintain it later.

Comment: @tenfour -- I know, I know. That poor smuck doesn't stand a chance. I guess I'm hopeing that the might of SO will rise up and create something which doesn't destroy lives.

Comment: @jjnguy If the alphabet is finite (which seems implied by "the input contains only letters"), then the language is regular.

Comment: @Christain, I will take your word for it I guess.

Comment: @jjnguy Posted an answer to prove my claim.

Comment: Looking again at the question, I think you were pretty close. Your last regex is searching for two consecutive characters - you just need some more in the middle: `(.)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1).*(.)(?<!\2.+)(?!.*\2)`, which looks like a much simpler approach. Oops. Maybe you should add your own answer `:P`

Comment: @Kobi -- Aha! Now I shall steal all the upvotes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another approach - the idea is the opposite of Bart's approach - I'm matching duplicated characters (which is somewhat easier), and count the rest:

```
^
(?>                 # Possessive group - do not backtrack!
    (.)             # Match a duplicated character
       (?:
         (?=.*\1)       # It can have a duplicate after itself
         |
         (?<=\1.+)      # Or it already had one
       )
    |               # Or, it isn't a duplicated character at all
    (?<Unique>.)    # Capture it as a unique character.
)+
$
(?<-Unique>){2}     # After we're done, check there were at least
                    # two unique characters
```

The main trick here is the use of the [possessive group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) - it makes sure the duplicated characters never backtrack, so I know the next dot will only capture a non-duplicated character.

In .Net, every capture of a group is added to a stack. `(?<-Unique>)` pops a capture from the stack, and fails if it's empty. It gives a nice  way of counting how many captures we've had.

Comment: Yes, I like it. I've not seen this possessive group before. Do you think it is common enough that people would recognise it when they read it?

Comment: @Buh Buh - I've answered enough regex questions to answer confidently - No. Possessive groups are *relatively* well known in the right crowd (they are common in many flavors), but overall such a regex may be hard to understand (the most common task here is changing `{2}` to another number, so that one should be OK). The commented regex you see here is taken *directly* from source code, you can (and should) add more comments and even include a link here - I think there are many explanations and links in this page.

Comment: Don't worry.  I have obliterated it with comments and unit tests.  I think it should be ok.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This *seems* to do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] values = { "abc", "abbc", "aabc", "aabb", "aabbcc", "abab", "abb" };
      string pattern = @"(?:(.)(?<=^(?:(?!\1).)*\1)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*$).*?){2,}";
      foreach (string value in values) {
         if (Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern)) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} valid", value);
         }
         else {   
            Console.WriteLine("{0} invalid", value);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

produces the output:

```
abc valid
abbc valid
aabc valid
aabb invalid
aabbcc invalid
abab invalid
abb invalid
```

as can be seen on Ideone: http://ideone.com/oU7a0

But the regex is a horrific thing!

I'll explain it later, if you want (I have to go now).

---

### EDIT

Okay, here's an explanation of this monstorisity (I hope!):

```
(?:                # start non-capture group 1
  (.)              #   capture any character, and store it in match group 1
  (?<=             #   start posisitve look-behind
    ^              #     match the start of the input string
    (?:(?!\1).)    #     if what is captured in match group 1 cannot be seen ahead, match the character
    *              #     repeat the previous zero or more times 
    \1             #     this is the `(.)` we're looking at
  )                #   end posisitve look-behind
  (?=              #   start posisitve look-ahead
    (?:(?!\1).)    #     if what is captured in match group 1 cannot be seen ahead, match the character
    *              #     repeat the previous zero or more times 
    $              #     match the end of the input string
  )                #   emd posisitve look-ahead
  .*?              #   match zero or more characters, un-greedy
)                  # end non-capture group 1
{2,}               # match non-capture group 1 at least 2 times
```

In plain English, it would be a bit like this:

```
+---                                                      # (
| match and group any character `C` at position `P`,      # (.)
|                                                         #
| and look from the start of the input all that way       #
| to `P` where there can't be any character like `C`      # (?<=^(?:(?!\1).)*\1)
| in between.                                             #
|                                                         #
| Also look from position `P` all the way to the end      #
| of the input where there can't be any character `C`     # (?=(?:(?!\1).)*$)
| in bewteen.                                             #
+---                                                      #
| if the previous isn't matched, consume any character    #
| un-greedy zero or more times (but the previous block    # .*?
| is always tried before this part matched the character) #
+---                                                      # )
|                                                         #
|                                                         # 
+----> repeat this at least 2 times                       # {2,}
```

---

### EDIT II

Let's say Kobi (`K`) is placed somewhere on top of a string, `"abcYbacZa"`, containing 9 characters:

```
              K
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
| a | b | c | Y | b | a | c | Z | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
p0  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8
```

and Kobi wants to know if the character at index 4, `Y`, is unique in the entire string. Kobi travels with his trusted minion, let's call his minion Bart (`B`), who get's the following assignment from Kobi:

### Step 1

Kobi: Bart, go back to the start of the input: `regex: (?<=^ ... )` (Bart will start at position 0: `p0`, which is the empty string just before the first `a`);

```
B             K
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
| a | b | c | Y | b | a | c | Z | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
p0  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8  p9
```

### Step 2

Then look ahead and determine if you *can't* see the character I've remembered in match group 1, `regex: (.)`, which is the character `Y`. So at position `p0`, Bart performs `regex: (?!\1)`. For `p0`, this holds true: Bart sees the character `a`, so `Y` is still unique. Bart advances to the next position `p1`, where he sees character `b`: all is still fine, and he makes another step to position `p2`, and so on: `regex: (?:(?!\1).)*`.

### Step 3

Bart is now at position `p3`:

```
            B K
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
| a | b | c | Y | b | a | c | Z | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
p0  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8  p9
```

and when he now looks ahead, he *does* see the character `Y`, of course, so `regex: (?!\1)` fails. But that character, where Kobi is still on, is consumed by the last `\1` in: `regex: (?:(?!\1).)*\1`. So after `p3`, Bart proudly tells Kobi: *"Yes, `Y` is indeed unique while looking behind us!"*. *"Good"*, says Kobi, *"now do the same, but instead of looking behind, look ahead, all the way up to the end of this string we're standing on, and make it snappy!"*.

### Step 4

Bart grumbles something unintelligible, but starts his journey at `p4`:

```
              K B
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
| a | b | c | Y | b | a | c | Z | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
p0  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8  p9
```

and when he looks ahead, he sees the character `b`, so the `regex: (?!\1)` holds true and the character `b` is consumed by `regex: .`. Bart repeats this zero or more times `regex: (?:(?!\1).)*` all the way to the end of the input `regex: (?:(?!\1).)*$`. He returns to Kobi again, and tells him: *"Yes, when looking ahead, `Y` is still unique!"*

So, the regex:

```
(.)(?<=^(?:(?!\1).)*\1)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*$)
```

will match any *single* character that is unique in the string.

### Step 5

The regex above can't simply be repeated 2 or more times, since that would only match 2 successive unique characters. So, we'll add a `regex: .*?` after it:

```
(.)(?<=^(?:(?!\1).)*\1)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*$).*?
                                        ^^^
```

that will consume the characters `b`, `a` and `c` in this case, and repeat *that* regex two times or more:

```
(?:(.)(?<=^(?:(?!\1).)*\1)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*$).*?){2,}
^^^                                           ^^^^^
```

So at the end, the substring `"YbacZ"` is matched from `"abcYbacZa"` because `Y` and `Z` are unique.

There you have it, as easy as pie, right? :)

Comment: Oh no. I think you just sinned against nature. That is a beast. If you do get time to expain it a bit I would be greatful.

Comment: Impressive. Sadly, I don't understand any of it, so I can't upvote it yet... `:)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Bart. I have gone with Kobi's as the accepted answer because I found it easier to understand.  As much as I like yours I don't think I can get away with putting a story into my source code  :)

Comment: @Buh Buh, yeah, I can imagine that. If I _had_ to do it with a regex and had to choose between mine and Kobi's, I'd go for his one too! You're welcome, of course.

Answer (score 2):

No Regex... LINQ!

```
"aabbcc".Distinct().Count()
```

---

Okay, so no can Linq.  But this (corrected, now that I understand the difference between "distinct" and "unique") would work:

```
bool hasAtLeastOneUniqueChar = 
    (from c in "aabbc"
    group c by c into grp
    where grp.Count() == 1
    select grp.Key).Any()
```

Comment: Yep I know.  Unfortunately for reasons beyond my control LINQ is not an option; it has to regex.  Thanks though.

Comment: Pisst... change .Any() to .Count() >= 2.

Comment: @BuhBuh: Why?  Thought you wanted to know if there was at least one letter that appeared only once.  The expression gets all characters that appear only once, and Any() returns true if there is at least one in the enumerable.  Unless you *actually* need TWO or more unique characters... Oh.  Derp.

Answer (score 2):

If the alphabet is finite (lets call it `LETTERS`), one may construct a regex with this pseudo code:

```
R := "";
for each (X in LETTERS) for each (Y in LETTERS) if (X!=Y)
    R += "|(^(?=[^X]*X[^X]*$)([^Y]*Y[^Y]*$))"
        .replaceAll("X",X).replaceAll("Y",Y);
R := R.substring(1);
```

R uses only regular constructions and positive lookahead (which amounts to an intersection of regular languages and is still regular), proving that **the language in question is indeed regular**.

Basically, this creates a union of regular languages containing "strings containing exactly one X and exactly one Y", for each pair of X and Y.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks.  It would be an awful regex if you wanted to write it by hand though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this non-.NET answer here because I spent all morning thinking about it...

Variable length lookback is crucial to the other solutions here, but .NET seems to be rare in supporting it (so far). So how to do it with lookahead only? This seems to work in Perl 5.12:

```
/(?x)
    ^ (?&BALANCED) (?&RIGHT1) (?&BALANCED) (?&RIGHT1)
    (?(DEFINE)
            (?<RIGHT1>  (.) (?! .* \g{-1} ) )
            (?<LEFT2>  (.) (?= .* \g{-1}) (?! .* \g{-1} .* \g{-1} ) )
            (?<OTHER>   (.) (?= .* \g{-1} .* \g{-1} ) )
            (?<BALANCED> (?&OTHER)* (?> (?&LEFT2) (?&BALANCED) (?&RIGHT1) (?&OTHER)* )* )
    )
/
```

The basic idea is to divide occurrences of characters into last (RIGHT1), next-to-last (LEFT2) and others. Unique characters only have a last occurrence, non-unique ones have a next-to-last as well -- so we want to make sure there's at least two 'last occurrences' more than 'next-to-last occurrences'.

By definition, next-to-last occurrences occur before last occurrences, so we can pretend that next-to-last and last occurrences are left and right brackets respectively, with other occurrences as filler. We then have a string where there's at least as many right brackets as left brackets, and we can be sure that every left bracket is matched (since it and every left bracket right of it each 'brings along' a right bracket even further to the right).

So we use a standard matched bracket recognizer, using recursive atomic matching, and look for two unmatched right brackets aka last occurrences.

Note that a given next-to-last occurrence will not necessarily match the last occurrence of the same character. In fact, it might match the last and only occurrence of a unique character, and the unmatched last occurrences might be 'left over' from non-unique characters -- the regexp cannot find the unique characters for you, a match just guarantees that they exist.

Comment: Oh man.  It's going to take me a while to get my head around that one.  Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

By popular demand I present my working answer.

```
(.)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1).*(.)(?<!\2.+)(?!.*\2)
```

To explain it:

```
(.)                    # match any character...
(?<!\1.+)              # ...which does not already exist in the input...
(?!.*\1)               # ..and does not exist later on in the input
                       # We have now found one unique character.

.*                     # allow for any number of random characters in the middle

(.)(?<!\2.+)(?!.*\2)   # Find a second unique character, 
                       # using the same technique.
```

-- Big thank-you to Kobi for finishing this for me in the comments.